# How do I draw a three-dimensional logarithmic graph in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I can draw LogPlot code with f(x,y)=1+x^2+3x^3 function for x should range from -10 to 10. Also,

I want to draw Log scale in 3D Plot graph of f(x,y)=1+x^2+y^3+3 x^3 y function for x and y should range from -10 to 10. But, But I can not do it. If you help me in this matter, I am delighted.

Best Regards,

Murat

Answer (score 4):

Kubas solution:

```
Plot3D[1 + x^2 + y^3 + 3 x^3 y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log10", AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is solved. Best Regards, Murat

Comment: @user54641 Please don't use answers for comments next time.

Comment: Dear Kubas,

Hi again,

In addition, I have a question.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDZLB.jpg


As you can see figure, I could draw the z-axis logarithmically with your recommendations. However, this axis seems to descend to the negative side. Instead of range 0, 2, 4, can I draw this axis at range of 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000?